# having hard time why this function doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Im having hard time to understand why this thing doesnt work. where is the problem? Is this the right way to pass in values to this function, are there other ways?

seqer.set_prefix = 'Q';
   seqer.set_seq = 1000;

Is it possibleto do it in this way:

```
sequer.set_prefix('Q');
```

---

```
var serial_maker = function () {
        var prefix = '';
        var seq = 0;
        return {
            set_prefix: function (p) {
                prefix = p;
            },
            set_seq: function (s) {
                seq = s;
            },
            gensym: function () {
                var result = prefix + seq;
                seq += 1;
                return result;
            }
        };
    }();
var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix = 'Q'; // is this the right way to pass in values to this function, are there other ways? is it possible to write like this sequer.set_prefix('Q);
seqer.set_seq = 1000; // same here?
seqer.gensym()
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript - you can generally treat them exactly like you would treat a normal function (except that they have no given identifier, unless you assign them to a name). [Here's a good tutorial about them](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/) - they are quite powerful, and I consider them to be one of the best things about JavaScript.

So yes, doing:

```
seqer.set_prefix = 'Q';
seqer.set_seq = 1000;
```

is incorrect. You are overwriting the funcitons with these constants. Your guess is correct - to call them, you would use:

```
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
```

By the way, there is another error in your function:

```
var serial_maker = function () {
        ...
        return {
            ...
        };
    }(); // <- right here
```

You're defining an anonymous function, but *calling it immediately*. So unfortunately, `var serial_maker` won't be a serial_maker - it'll be the returned object. Of course, the subsequent `var seqer = serial_maker();` will fail, because the object is not a function.

Comment: thanks for the explantion but now testing. I notice that you can't change the values of prefix and set outside the function right? THis: var seqer = serial_maker(); seqer.set_prefix = 'Q'; seqer.set_seq = 1000; seqer.gensym( ); will never work actually cuz those variables are privat right?.... – YoniGeek

Comment: @YoniGeek: No, you _can_ set them. JavaScript doesn't really have any concept of 'private' members. If you can access them, then you can replace them - it's highly dynamic. So yes, doing `seqer.set_prefix = 'Q';` will **really** replace the whole function `set_prefix` with the value `Q`.

Answer (score 0):

`set_prefix` and `set_seq` are methods. To use them, do it this way:

```
var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
seqer.gensym();
```

Also, to create a `serial_maker()` "module", you need to have either these to create it.

```
var serial_maker = (function () {
    //code here
}());

//or

var serial_maker = (function () {
    //code here
})();
```

Comment: @josef thanks going thru yr answer. the first part is correct but the second one tough. if u write like this: var serial_maker = (function () {
    //code here
})(); then u cant write :serial_marker(); but serial_marker; NOW if u want to write serial_marker(); then you have to change the whole scope like this: function () {
    //code here
};